# Change console height and width in c

Tags: c, codeblocks

Do you know which library or function should I use to change Console Application width and height in C without using windows or GUI header?
Im using code:blocks .

Comment: Telepathy is not supported, you really do have to call SetConsoleWindowInfo().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of the console, it is simply another window, except that it is considered "special" by Windows since it serves a certain purpose, which means you have two options:

- use the console API, a small subset of the Windows API, or
- get the window handle of the console somehow and resize it directly.

Both require use of the Windows API, so your answer is to use the Windows API. You can't avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

try [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library... It will do more than you want